# Does jruby have an issue with java.sql.DriverManager? No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jruby

I am trying to update a jruby application

FROM java 1.8

TO Java 11.

Cannot get a simple jruby program to make a connection.  I wrote the same program in java, and it connects just fine, so I know that the issue is somehow in jruby.

```
require 'java'
require 'jdbc/mysql'

# Load the JDBC driver class

Jdbc::MySQL.load_driver
jdbc-mysql

# Set up the JDBC connection parameters

url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase?user=root"

# Connect to the database
conn = java.sql.DriverManager.get_connection(url)`
```

```
irb(main):027:0> conn = java.sql.DriverManager.get_connection(url)
Traceback (most recent call last):
       16: from org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$rbCatch.call(org/jruby/RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$rbCatch.gen)
       15: from org.jruby.RubyKernel.catch(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1237)
       14: from org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$0$loop.call(org/jruby/RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$0$loop.gen)
       13: from org.jruby.RubyKernel.loop(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1507)
       12: from org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$3$eval.call(org/jruby/RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$3$eval.gen)
       11: from org.jruby.RubyKernel.eval(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1091)
       10: from org.jruby.RubyKernel.evalCommon(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1129)
        9: from RUBY.evaluate((irb):27)
        8: from org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeStaticDirect(org/jruby/javasupport/JavaMethod.java:369)
        7: from org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(org/jruby/javasupport/JavaMethod.java:457)
        6: from java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:566)
        5: from jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(jdk/internal/reflect/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        4: from jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(jdk/internal/reflect/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        3: from jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        2: from java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(java/sql/DriverManager.java:251)
        1: from java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(java/sql/DriverManager.java:702)
Java::JavaSql::SQLException (No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase?user=root)
```

The issue seems to be that the [DriverManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) is not doing what the JavaDocs says it should.

When the method getConnection is called, the DriverManager will attempt to locate a suitable driver from amongst those loaded at initialization and those loaded explicitly using the same classloader as the current applet or application.

What did work, was explicitly creating a driver, and using the connect method.

```
require 'jdbc/mysql'

Jdbc::MySQL.load_driver

url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase"
driver = Java::com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver.new
props = java.util.Properties.new
props.setProperty("user", "root")
props.setProperty("password", "")

conn = driver.connect(url,props)
```

I also created a java program do directly test essentially the same code.  It worked fine with Java 11 (same stack).

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;

Connection conn = null;

conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase?" + "user=root");
```

Comment: This likely has to do with order of initialization of `DriverManager`, and on which classpath / class loader the JDBC driver is actually provided. If `DriverManager` has been initialized **before** the JDBC driver is available on the classpath / provided by a class loader, then automatic driver loading will not have found the driver (because it wasn't available yet), and this is done only **once**, and initialization by explicitly loading the driver class (e.g. with Java's `Class.forName`, or by instantiating a driver like you do) is one of the few options left.

Comment: same issue found with sqlite